# Need help adding a title attribute to Standard/Custom Field labels

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects, helptext

I was wondering if there is a way to add a description/tooltip on Field labels for Standard/Custom objects from the UI. In HTML this would be done via the 'title' attribute, but was looking for ways to do this in Salesforce.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the field's Help Text in Setup->Object Manager:

[image: Object Manager screenshot]

This yields a hoverable info icon with tooltip for users:

[image: tooltip image]

Comment: That was quick! Thank you, I must have over looked that, I was quite sure I did this in the past but was unable to figure it out. That is helpful, thank you!